# What Spring Security uses to generate OAuth2 tokens?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

How Spring Security generates the security token or what algorithms it follows to generate the OAuth2 token?

We can use JWT or open-id, etc. as an authorization token but by default what it uses?

Comment: Do you use Spring Security 5.x or Spring Security OAuth 2?

Comment: @dur, I am using Spring Security 5.x in that using  Spring Security OAuth 2 implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are using [Spring Security OAuth2](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html) as an authorization server then the default for authorization code  is a random value, see [RandomValueAuthorizationCodeServices](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/code/RandomValueAuthorizationCodeServices.html):

> Base implementation for authorization code services that generates a random-value authorization code.

and the default for access token and refresh token is a random UUID, see [DefaultTokenServices](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultTokenServices.html):

> Base implementation for token services using random UUID values for the access token and refresh token values.

Comment: Are these two different implementations of OAuth, Spring Security 5.x and Spring Security OAuth 2?

Comment: @Ali786: Yes, but AFAIK Spring Security 5 only supports the resource server not the authorization server.